# My Mac is 10.7.5 and Xcode 4.6.1 But I can't install cordova 2.5.0 with xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, xcode4.5, phonegap-plugins

My Mac is 10.7.5 and My Xcode is 4.6.1. Previously cordova 2.2.0 was installed in my system.

But when I upgrade my Xcode from lower version to 4.6.1 and downloaded the latest cordova I'm

unable to integrate ios and cordova. terminal.app says "No such file or directory".

Note: I've already extract the phonegap package and drag and drop the ios bin folder to

terminal. When I drag the bin terminal.app says : is a directory. How can I solve this?

Comment: try to navigate to the iOS folder using cd command and then try to create the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a **Terminal** window, navigated inside the `bin` folder and executed the `./create` command whith the requested parameters.

I didn't even tried to make it dragging it.

Tell us if it worked this way.

** **UPDATE** **

> Determine where on your system you will locate the Xcode project files
>   for your application. For this tutorial I created a CordovaXY
>   directory under my Documents folder: ~/Documents/CordovaXY where the X
>   and Y refer the to Cordova version

I created the folder `cordova25`, then...

```
cd ~/Downloads/phonegap-2.5.0/lib/ios/bin
./create ~/Documents/cordova25/myappname com.mydomain.myappname myappname
```

This will create your project `myappname` inside `cordova25` folder. Just execute the `.xcodeproj` and **XCode** will launch and mount it.

Here you have some more info about the common known issues of creating a project like this. This doesn't mean it will happen to you, but just in case it does, here you have it.

> http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Comment: Mohammeds-MacBook-Pro:Applications Enayet$ cd ~
Mohammeds-MacBook-Pro:~ Enayet$ cd /Applications/
Mohammeds-MacBook-Pro:Applications Enayet$ open phonegap-2.5.0
The file /Applications/phonegap-2.5.0 does not exist. (I've added this command and failed. Please help :()

Comment: It says--- The file /Applications/phonegap-2.5.0 does not exist.

Comment: @Holy Update my answer with more info.